# Product of elements from Direct summand in the direct sum abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G = H \oplus K$ be abelian group. Now, I follow the definition of direct sum from Wikipedia which is
[image]

Now, we choose two element (both of them are not identity) $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ ($h, k \neq e_{G}$).
When I tried to think about the element $h \cdot k$, then a contradiction seems to appear.

Let's assume  the element $h \cdot k \in H \Rightarrow h^{-1}\cdot  h \cdot k \in H   \Rightarrow k \in H$. Contradiction.

Similarly If assume  the element $h \cdot k \in K \Rightarrow k^{-1} \cdot  h \cdot k \in K   \Rightarrow h \in K$. Contradiction.

The element $h \cdot k $ doesn't seem to belong anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Those come from $G$ itself.

Note that $H$ and $K$ are *subgroups* of $G$. Direct sum does not try to take two random groups and create a new one, it's rather about making sure that the subsets you've taken actually form the original group.

Comment: the element $h \cdot k$ should be in $G$ because it is a group and since $G = H \oplus K$, we should have $h \cdot k $ either in $H$ or in $K$ (if it is not identity). But it doesn't seem to belong to either.

Comment: Which part of the definition of the direct sum makes you think that $h \cdot k$ should be in $H$ or $K$?

Comment: $G = H \oplus K$. So, the smallest subgroup that contain both $H$ and $K$ is $G$ and $H \cap K =e$.

Comment: Right. I might sound repetitive, but let me try to rephrase. $h \cdot k$ is from $G$, and it cannot be an element of one of those subgroups.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that $H$ and $K$ generates $G$ means that $H \cup K =G$ which is not the case. Just one more thing, if you can clarify, I understand the non-constructive way of saying that $G = H \oplus K$ is the smallest subgroup that contain both $H$ and $K$. Can you explain what does this mean constructively. for e.g. a cyclic group is generated by an element $x$. So, $G = <x>$. Is the terminology that $H,K$ generates $G$ a misnomer? and in the "right sense" it is just the smallest subgroup that contains $H,K$.

Comment: Sure. A good example would be $G = \{1, z, z^2, \ldots, z^{n-1}\}$, where $z = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}$. Note that $z ^ n = 1$, so basically the group is generated by multiplying $z$ by itself many times. Now about terminology. I personally would translate $G = H \cup K$ as "$H$ and $K$ sum up to $G$", and $G = H \oplus K$ as "combinations of $H$ and $K$ form $G$". I think it's just a matter of getting used to those symbols :)